# As interpreted this for in c

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, visual-c++

I got the question of what makes this for, I have seen only the implementation

```
for(i=0;nlist[i].nid!=0;i++)
        {}
        nlist[i].nid=n_id;
        nlist[i].add=temp;
```

nlist is an array of type structure

Struct

```
struct node
{
    int id; 
    struct node *l[MAX_CONN+1];
    int cost[MAX_CONN+1];  
    struct node **next;
    int *mincost;

};
typedef struct node nodes; 
struct record 

{
    int nid;
    struct node *add;
};
typedef struct record records;
records nlist[MAX_NODES+1]={0};
```

full function

> ```
>     FILE *f;
>     int d;
>     int i=0,j=0,n_id,n_cost;
>     nodes *temp=0,*temp1=0;
>
>     if((f=fopen("graph.txt","r"))== NULL)
>     {
>         printf("Error opening file.\n");
>         exit(1);
>     }
>     memset(nlist, 0, sizeof(struct record) * MAX_NODES);
>     count=0;
>     do /*first get the id and address of all nodes*/
>     {
>         fscanf(f,"%d",&n_id);
>         for(i=0;nlist[i].nid!=0;i++)
>         {
>             if(n_id==nlist[i].nid)
>             {
>                 printf("Id already exists.");
>                 return;
>             }
>         }
>         temp=(nodes *)malloc(sizeof(nodes));
>         if (temp == 0)
>         {
>            printf("ERROR: Out of memory\n");
>            return;
>         }
>         memset(temp, 0, sizeof(struct node));
>         temp->id=n_id;
>         temp->l[MAX_CONN+1]=0;
>         temp->cost[MAX_CONN+1]=0;
>         for(i=0;nlist[i].nid!=0;i++)
>         {}
>         nlist[i].nid=n_id;
>         nlist[i].add=temp;
>         count++;
>         while((d=fgetc(f)!=';'))
>         {}
>     }while((d=fgetc(f))!=EOF);
>
>     rewind(f);
>
>     for(i=0;i<count;i++) /*now get the information of all nodes connections.*/
>     {
>         fscanf(f,"%*d");
>
>         temp=nlist[i].add;
>         while((d=fgetc(f)!=';'))
>         {
>             fscanf(f,"%d-%d",&n_id,&n_cost);
>             for(j=0;nlist[j].nid!=0;j++)
>             {
>                 if(nlist[j].nid==n_id)
>                 {
>                     temp1=nlist[j].add;
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>             for(j=0;temp->cost[j]!=0;j++)
>             {}
>             temp->cost[j]=n_cost;
>             temp->l[j]=temp1;
>         }
>     }
>     fclose(f);
> ```

Comment: erm, what?...........

Comment: what is nlist? structure? union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indenting is misleading. It should be indented more like this:

```
for(i=0;nlist[i].nid!=0;i++) {
    /* empty loop */
}
nlist[i].nid=n_id;
nlist[i].add=temp;
```

I think that what it's supposed to do is as follows: The `for` loop advances `i` from 0 until it finds an element of `nlist` that has a null value for its `nid` field. It then sets the `nid` and `add` fields at that index to `n_id` and `temp`, respectively.

I should add that this is very dangerous code. If `i` advances past the end of `nlist` without finding an appropriate slot, the program is very likely to crash or otherwise misbehave. It certainly won't behave correctly.

Comment: more likely those statements should be in loop!! But given the loop termination condition using i, it makes little sense anyway.

Comment: @MitchWheat - That, or some comments, would greatly improve readability. My preference would be to move the `for` into a function with a meaningful name (e.g., `findFirstAvailableSlot()` that returns an index (or -1 if none is available).

Comment: My preference would be to dig a big hole and drop the code into it! :)

Comment: @MitchWheat - Heh. Yeah, I agree.

Comment: "*It certainly won't behave correctly.*" It will appear to behave correctly *sometimes*, hence [the learntoprogramdottv strcat error](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=592_odiT6Dg&t=5m24s) going unnoticed by the author (despite numerous comments)...

Comment: The code does not develop I'm trying to understand what to correct.

Comment: @user1825955 - I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment. What is the code _supposed_ to do? If you explain that, perhaps we can tell you how to change the code so it works properly.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue - Indeed. I think of "misbehave" as including "write to portions of memory that should not be altered", but it's better to be explicit about it. Nice link, too. :)

Comment: I have a file that contains:
1, State :2-2 :3-4 :5-4; \n
2, State2 :1-2 :3-3;\n
I use this algorithm for djkstra ()
The function here is not all, is a part of it, I put it right now to see what he does.

Comment: Additionally, the code provided in the OP would correctly advance to the first unused item, providing it doesn't advance beyond the end of the array.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue - Good catch. I don't know why I misread OP's loop condition. Must be getting too late for me to be posting on SO. :(

Comment: @user1825955 - Perhaps you should post a separate question that includes all the relevant code and data, a description of what the code _should_ be doing, a description of how it is failing to do it, and what you have tried to do to fix it. That's a far different question than the one you posted here, which was "what does this code do"?

Comment: That is why I only offer the for, I wanted to see how they interpreted this to understand for more code and to correct it, anyway thanks for the comments.